# .text is scrambled with numbers and special keys in BeautifuSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, proxy, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello I am currently using Python 3, BeautifulSoup 4 and, requests to scrape some information from [supremenewyork.com](http://supremenewyork.com) UK. I have implemented a proxy script (that I know works) into the script. The only problem is that this website does not like programs to scrape this information automatically and so they have decided to scramble this script which I think makes it unusable as text.

**My question:** is there a way to get the text without using the `.text` thing and/or is there a way to get the script to read the text? and when it sees a special character like `#` to skip over it or to read the text when it sees `&` skip until it sees `;`?

because basically how this website scrambles the text is by doing this. Here is an example, the text shown when you inspect element is:

```
supre&#65279;me&#65279;tshi&#65279;rt
```

Which is supposed to say "supreme t-shirt" and so on (you get the idea, they don't use letters to scramble only numbers and special keys)

this `&#65279;` is kind of highlighted in a box automatically when you inspect the element using a VPN on the UK supreme website, and is different than the text (which isn't highlighted at all). And whenever I run my script without the proxy code onto my local [supremenewyork.com](http://supremenewyork.com), It works fine (but only because of the code, not being scrambled on my local website and I want to pull this info from the UK website) any ideas? here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

categorys = ['jackets', 'shirts', 'tops_sweaters', 'sweatshirts', 'pants', 'shorts', 't-shirts', 'hats', 'bags', 'accessories', 'shoes', 'skate']
catNumb = 0

#use new proxy every so often for testing (will add something that pulls proxys and usses them for you.
UK_Proxy1 = '51.143.153.167:80'

proxies = {
   'http': 'http://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
   'https': 'https://' + UK_Proxy1 + '',
}

for cat in categorys:
    catStr = str(categorys[catNumb])
    cUrl = 'http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/' + catStr
    proxy_script = requests.get(cUrl, proxies=proxies).text
    bSoup = BeautifulSoup(proxy_script, 'lxml')
    print('\n*******************"'+ catStr.upper() + '"*******************\n')
    catNumb += 1
    for item in bSoup.find_all('div', class_='inner-article'):
        url = item.a['href']
        alt = item.find('img')['alt']
        req = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com' + url)
        item_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
        name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
        #name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name')
        style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model').text
        #style = item_soup.find('p', itemprop='model')
        print (alt +(' --- ')+ name +(' --- ')+ style)
        #print(alt)
        #print(str(name))
        #print (str(style))
```

When I run this script I get this error:

> name = item_soup.find('h1', itemprop='name').text
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

And so what I did was I un-hash-tagged the stuff that is hash-tagged above, and hash-tagged the other stuff that is similar but different, and I get some kind of `str` error and so I tried the `print(str(name))`. I am able to print the alt fine (with every script, the alt is not scrambled), but when it comes to printing the name and style all it prints is a `None` under every alt code is printed.

I have been working on fixing this for days and have come up with no solutions. can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own answer using this solution:

```
thetable = soup5.find('div', class_='turbolink_scroller')
items = thetable.find_all('div', class_='inner-article')
for item in items:
    alt = item.find('img')['alt']
    name = item.h1.a.text
    color = item.p.a.text
    print(alt,' --- ', name, ' --- ',color)
```